# Mysql migration from 4 to 5.7

Tags: mysql, database-migration, data-migration

I'm migrating a database from MySQL 4 to MySQL 5.7
I'm getting some problems with character sets.

On the MySQL 4, for example, a table as the definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `bol_comentarios` (
  `processo` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `data_hora` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `autor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `texto` text,
  `cliente` enum('true','false') default NULL,
  `estado` int(11) NOT NULL default '-1',
  `conclusao` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`processo`,`data_hora`,`autor`)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

I change the TYPE to Engine and create the table with no problem and create the table in MySQL 5.7
When i'm trying to import data, the problem appears in the `texto` field.

If i create the table with UTF-8 then a can insert the data, but special character end up like '�'

If i try to create a table with Latin1 then this error: Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD' for column .

Can someone help me?

I'm using RedHat 7.2.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hopefully you can abandon the MyISAM engine. That thing's terribly creaky and disastrously dangerous in production use.

Comment: Probably you have a mismatch in how the characters are encoded in application, database connection, and database levels. You need to keep these settings in sync.

Comment: What is the character set in the original table? I guess it is `utf8_*`, that's why you have the `\xEF\xBF\xBD` byte sequence. Try `utf8_general_ci` charset for that field.